# Strange values of 2F1 function in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

Why hyp2f1 from scipy gives 1? However it should be

[image]

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
x = np.arange(0,2,0.01)
y = special.hyp2f1(-1/2, 1/2, 2, -400/(1-8/9*np.cos(x)**2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using Python 2 for that. The problem is the division operator in Python 2: Dividing an integer by an integer gives an integer. For example, `1/2` is `0`. If one of the operands is a floating point the result is what you expect: `float(1) / 2 == 1. / 2 == 0.5`

The following will work as expected:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

x = np.arange(0,2,0.01)
y = special.hyp2f1(-1/2, 1/2, 2, -400/(1-8/9*np.cos(x)**2))
```

Alternatively, convert the parameters to float (e.g. using the `.` notation):

```
y = special.hyp2f1(-1./2, 1./2, 2., -400/(1-8/9.*np.cos(x)**2))
```